# Good implementation of scalable JavaScript application architecture (Sandbox by Nicholas Zakas)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, sandbox, modularity

I recently watched a good video with regards to a modular JavaScript architecture including a sandbox. I was wondering if there is anything that's been implemented in the wild?

Is the framework downloadable or an implementation of it?

The videos were great but they were only theory and no code was available. Original video [is here](http://cryptochaos.com/highly-recommended-scalable-javascript-applic).

Comment: I made an YUI implementation 2 years ago and continue to maintain it. You can check it on github. https://github.com/miiicasa/module

Comment: I didn't look through the code, but there is https://github.com/aranm/scalable-javascript-architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a comparison about different implementations of this theory by Zakas.

I've compared...

1. [ScaleApp](http://scaleapp.org/)
2. Kernel.js
3. Terrifically

After checking all pros and cons I decided to use Hydra.js (I needed to extend modules easily), but the most important is to know what do you need/expect of these type of frameworks and make your own comparison.

These are the topics I checked:

- Framework agnostic
- Documentation
- Size
- Trending
- Allow multiple module instances
- Less coupling
- Easy testing of modules
- Unit tested
- Workshop/Video/Demos/Slides
- Extensible (plugins or similar)
- Allow extension of modules
- Company Support
- Minimized versions
- License
- Community
- Maturity of project
- Last commit
- Mentions in blogs/webs
- Github
- Dependencies
- Watchers
- Forks / Development Team Size
- Error Manager
- Async modules load
- Deferred-Promise integration
- Can be used in Browser and Node.js

Tell me if need more help.

Update:

I'm checking a new framework that is in development preview ['Backbone Aura'](http://addyosmani.github.com/aura/) from Addyosmani

Comment: Hydra.js looks good, but when you're recommending a framework that you developed, it would be best if you disclosed that upfront so it doesn't seem like you're trying to put one over on us. Otherwise this is a helpful list +1

Comment: Ok, I remove Hydra.js from the comparison list. Sorry for the misunderstanding.;)

Comment: No problem at all - I did further research on Hydra.js and found it to be reputable and worthy of consideration. It just gave me pause when I realized you were the developer and figured others might have the same reaction.

Comment: hi, any good examples of backbone.js modules and hydra.js?, does hydra uses any AMD library ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of boilerplateJS. After couple of complex JS projects, I wanted to compile my experience in building complex application in JS as a open source reference architecture. BoilerplateJS handles all concerns that are discussed by Nicholas, but not restricted to the ideas presented there.

BoilerplateJS lets you to structure your complex product suite in to product-modules and UI components. There are several samples implemented to follow in the reference architecture code base.

http://boilerplatejs.org/

Among other concerns it handles are:
 - structuring the solution
 - creating a module hierarchy
 - Dependency management
 - Event based messaging,
 - Routing and embeddable components
 - Unit testing
 - Localization
 - Document generation
 - JS optimizations and obfuscation

See it in action here:
http://boilerplatejs.org/samples/productsuite/index.html